# GSON Deserialize JSON with no variable names

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to figure out how to de-serialize this in GSON. So here's what I have so far...

I have a KLM file imported into a fusion table I'm able to retrieve from google and it looks like so:

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "description",
  "name",
  "Address",
  "geometry"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "Address: Cape Colony and Commodore Drive San Jose, CA 95133",
   "Berryessa Community Garden",
   "Cape Colony and Commodore Drive San Jose, CA 95133",
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
      -121.862809,
      37.375257,
      0.0
     ]
    }
   }
  ],
  [
   "Address: S. 6th Street and Bestor Street San Jose, CA 95112",
   "Bestor Community Garden",
   "S. 6th Street and Bestor Street San Jose, CA 95112",
   {
    "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
      -121.873797,
      37.32357,
      0.0
     ]
    }
   }
  ], ...
```

I'm trying to figure out how to de-serialize this in GSON. I have the basic setup:

Async call for Deserialization of the json response:

```
            //Deserialization
            Type deserializationType = new TypeToken<FusionTableModel>() {}.getType();
            FusionTableModel responceWrapper = gson.fromJson(sb.toString(), deserializationType);
```

Class:

```
public class FusionTableModel {

    private String kind; 
    private ArrayList<String> columns; 

}
```

Comment: So what is your question? Are you getting some kind of error? If so, can you post the error logs? On first inspection, your FusionTableModel is not nearly filled out enough to mirror the json.

Comment: @JohnWhite "I'm trying to figure out how to de-serialize this in GSON."

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {

@Expose
private String kind;
@Expose
private List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
@Expose
private List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

public String getKind() {
    return kind;
}

public void setKind(String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
}

public List<String> getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(List<String> columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}

public List<List<String>> getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(List<List<String>> rows) {
    this.rows = rows;

}

}
```

In the future there are plenty of json to pojo tools out there that you can use to generate java from json structure.

Comment: Which do you recommend since this is throwing me an error?

Comment: What do you mean its throwing you an error? What error is it throwing?

Comment: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Comment: Can you post some logs or something? it's really hard to just gather what you mean from a single line.